# How to remove the shadow from the action bar in android API 23 and Greater

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

Can you tell me how to remove shadow from the ActionBar

I tried `android:elevation` and `android:windowContentOverlay`
none of them worked

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please put examples of your code, so we can help you find a mistake in your code. Because `android:elevation` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try app:elevation="0dp" in xml like this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_editprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <com.hifiveapp.customeview.CustomFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            style="@style/toolbar_text_style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/new_story_title" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```